# How can I iterate through JSON objects using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I ultimately want to create inverted indexes using my JSON dataset. I know how to parse through one JSON object but how can I iterate through many? Here is what I have working:

File1:

```
{
    "doc_id": "2324jos",
    "screen_name": "twitter_user101",
    "tweet_text": "Its a beautiful day to be productive",
    "hashtags": "[]",
    "links": "[]",
    "place_type": "city",
    "place_name": "Evergreen Park",
    "created_at": "2019-02-08 22:24:03"
}
```

My code:

```
public class ParseJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // this is the key object to convert JSON to Java
        Tweet tweet;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            File json = new File("test.json");
            tweet = mapper.readValue(json, Tweet.class);
            System.out.println("Java object created from JSON String :");
            System.out.println(tweet);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class Tweet {
    public String doc_id;
    public String screen_name;
    public String tweet_text;
    public String hashtags;
    public String links;
    public String place_type;
    public String place_name;
    public String created_at;

    public Tweet() {

    }

    public Tweet(String doc_id, String screen_name, String tweet_text, String hashtags, String links, String place_type, String place_name, String created_at) {
        this.doc_id = doc_id;
        this.screen_name = screen_name;
        this.tweet_text = tweet_text;
        this.hashtags = hashtags;
        this.links = links;
        this.place_name = place_name;
        this.place_type = place_type;
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return doc_id + screen_name + tweet_text;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to iterate through this JSON file which has 2 JSON objects in an array:

File2:

```
[
    {
        "doc_id": "2324jos",
        "screen_name": "b'LIBBYRULZ'",
        "tweet_text": "@ABC ya'll be lying",
        "hashtags": "[]",
        "links": "[]",
        "place_type": "city",
        "place_name": "Evergreen Park",
        "created_at": "2019-02-08 22:24:03"
    },
    {
        "doc_id": "8982hol",
        "screen_name": "b'eddylee_1'",
        "tweet_text": "Hungry for money",
        "hashtags": "[]",
        "links": "[]",
        "place_type": "city",
        "place_name": "Manhattan",
        "created_at": "2/7/2019 17:01"
    }
]
```

How can I adjust my above code using Jackson to do so where the doc_id is the unique key? I want to be able to return all the data in each JSON object for each doc_id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To parse an array of JSON objects using Jackson:

```
Tweet[] tweets = mapper.readValue(json, Tweet[].class);
```

should do the trick. See below:

```
public class ParseJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Tweet[] tweets;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            File json = new File("test.json");
            tweets = mapper.readValue(json, Tweet[].class);
            System.out.println("Java object created from JSON String :");
            Arrays.asList(tweets).forEach(System.out::println); // Prints each element in the array
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - can you show this maybe with some more context - I'm getting error: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of Tweet out of START_ARRAY token

Comment: You're getting that exception because you are trying to map a JSON array to a java Object. You need to map the JSON array to either a java List of objects, or java array of objects.

Comment: Thanks Matt - I'm still having some trouble can you reproduce the code above with your edits? If so I'll mark this as the accepted answer :)

Comment: Just added your ParseJson class to the above answer!

Answer (score 3):

You could try to put it in a list so you can iterate on it:

```
List<Tweet> data = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Tweet>>(){});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the TypeFactory to create a `CollectionType` and use it to parse the JSON as `List<Tweet>`.

```java
CollectionType tweetListType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, Tweet.class);
List<Tweet> tweets = mapper.readValue(json, tweetListType);
tweets.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Here is the complete example you shared:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.CollectionType;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ParseJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // this is the key object to convert JSON to Java
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            File json = new File("test.json");
            CollectionType tweetListType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, Tweet.class);
            List<Tweet> tweets = mapper.readValue(json, tweetListType);
            System.out.println("Java objects created from JSON String:");
            tweets.forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the import for this?

Comment: CollectionType import?
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.CollectionType;

Comment: awesome thank you this worked, and improved my understanding of collectiontype!